# HTACCES rewrite, just does not wat I want (preserve everything after the slash)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying different rewrite rules all day, but I just don`t cannot get it working in the way I want.

What I need:

- http://www.example.com/**page**
  to redirect to
- http://example.com/**page**

Now, every rule I try, as soon as I add www. to my URL, it just redirects to the homepage, instead of the page I intended to visit.

I use Magento, maybe it is something with my settings within Magento?

PS. I tried several rules, including this one:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: your rules should work, can you post the full .htacess ?

Comment: It seems to be a session issue, cleared cache en sessions, en it does more like I want know. Will test a few things to make sure it works